Do floating point rounding errors affect random number generators
Several random number generators I've used return numbers between 0 and 1, such as JavaScript's Math.random()
It's also notoriously true that floating point numbers have an issue with storing specific values.
So, are any commonly used random number generators affected by floating point rounding errors?  Like some numbers would never be randomly generated by it?

RNGs typically work with integers internally, but the "randomness" in the integer bits can be used to sample floats. You're right to assume that many floats will not typically be sampled, but then again many floats are not generally useful as RNG output (e.g. negative zero, NaNs, subnormal numbers). If you need a stream of random bits in JS, the cryptography APIs are likely more useful than Math.random().

@amon I was more interested in the idea of holes in the output range.  For example, many languages treat .3 as .3 * 4 x 10 ^ -17.  I would assume this would mean a function like Math.random() would never return 3 x 10 ^ 17 in a sufficiently large range.  That's an extreme example, but perhaps there are rounding errors affecting smaller ranges.

You're right that some floats will not typically be generated. There are approximately 2^63 finite double-precision floats, but the algorithm discussed in the answers generates an uniform distribution of only 2^52 different values. They can be rescaled so that they're not confined to the range [0, 1), but that only gives you a different selection of 2^52 distinct numbers. This is not due to rounding problems – it's sufficient here to think of floats as weird 52-bit integers that have variable step size. But yes, when using addition, rounding may further reduce the set of generated floats.

Most real numbers cannot be represented as floating point values. There are infinitely many real numbers in any range however small, but a numeric type on a digital computer can only represent a finite set of different numbers.
So obviously a random number generator cannot generate numbers which cannot be represented by the numeric type which is used. But it should be able to generate all the possible numbers which can be represented (to get as much randomness as possible) and each number should have equal likelihood of occurring.
But there is a further issue here! Since floating point numbers are represented internally as a significant (aka mantissa) and a (base-2) exponent, the representable numbers are not evenly distributed. E.g. the range from 1..2 have the same amount of representable numbers as the the range 2..4 which is twice as large. In other words the representable numbers gets denser towards 0. So if all representable numbers are equally likely, the distribution will skew towards the low range, which doesn't feel random!
To avoid this we can generate a random number with a fixed exponent and only use randomness for the bits of the mantissa. This makes the number "less random" than we would expect (e.g. a random 64 bit float only actually have 52 bits of randomness corresponding to the mantissa.) but in return we get even distribution.
Just out of curiosity I checked the source code for the Random class in .net:
    public override double NextDouble() =>
        // As described in http://prng.di.unimi.it/:
        // "A standard double (64-bit) floating-point number in IEEE floating point format has 52 bits of significand,
        //  plus an implicit bit at the left of the significand. Thus, the representation can actually store numbers with
        //  53 significant binary digits. Because of this fact, in C99 a 64-bit unsigned integer x should be converted to
        //  a 64-bit double using the expression
        //  (x >> 11) * 0x1.0p-53"
        (NextUInt64() >> 11) * (1.0 / (1ul << 53));

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.Xoshiro256StarStarImpl.cs
Here it starts with a random 64-bit integer, reduce it to 53 bits (because a double-precision floating point has 53 bit mantiassa) and then divide by 2^53.
Dividing by a multiple of 2 is a "safe" operation on floating points and will not round away any randomness (unless the number is too small to represent, but we know this is not the case here).

(+1) It is claimed that JavaScript's Math.random() simply maps to whatever the browser provides. According to http://prng.di.unimi.it/, the site mentioned in the snippet, all commonly used browsers use S. Vigno's xorshift128+ PRNG, which delivers unsigned 64-bit integers. These are then converted do IEEE-754 double in [0,1) using the multiplication method from the snippet: (x >> 11) * 0x1.0p-53. Therefore, other than zero, no random number generated will be less than 2**(-53), which seems worth highlighting (OP question regarding "some numbers would never be randomly generated by it").


It's also notoriously true that floating point numbers have an issue with storing specific values.

No, people have incorrect assumptions about what numbers can be stored in a floating point number. People incorrectly believe that floating point types store real numbers, while in reality they can only store a subset of the real numbers.
A single precision IEEE 754 floating point number can represent 230 numbers between 0 and 1. That is a lot of numbers, but still a far cry from the infinite numbers that exist in that interval. In that way, all RNGs are unable to generate some of the numbers that exist between 0 and 1.
Within the constraints of the floating point type, it depends on the quality of the RNG and the intended distribution over the 0 to 1 range if it can generate all numbers that can be represented by the type.
As the density of the representable numbers is not uniform (there are significantly more floating point numbers in 0 to 0.5 than in 0.5 to 1), the designers of an RNG can choose to generate only numbers with the same exponent. That would give them a uniform distribution (which is considered a good thing), at the cost of being able to generate fewer numbers (223 for a single precision floating point type, 252 for double precision). Here you have to weigh the properties of a good RNG against the properties of the floating point type.

"but a good quality RNG will generate all representable numbers." - Will it? I'm pretty sure, especially with denormals, that numbers very close to zero are over-represented in the possible numbers between 0 and 1. So if an RNG can generate every representable value, it won't be a uniform distribution. I'd rather expect the RNG to fix the exponent and generate every possible mantissa for that. For single-precision float that's 2^23 numbers, but JS uses double-precision, 52 bits of mantissa.

@SebastianRedl that could be compensated for with Monte-Carlo technique, for example. Not that anyone would.

Yes, but not in the way you are thinking
Every psuedo-random number generator of which I am aware, and certainly every commonly used one, does not generate a random float - it generates a random binary number of a certain length (e.g. 64- bits, or 32- bits in older implementations). The best current implementations are very high quality and produce bit streams that pass stringent tests of randomness, and can be treated as such for most non-cryptographic purposes. These binary numbers then get converted into a random floating point number in a number of different ways, most often by using a subset of those bits to generate a number in the range [0, 1) either by bit twiddling or floating-point multiplication. This method is used by the standard libraries of Java, Javascript, and C# among others.
But because this approach truncates the number of bits used (e.g. using 52 or 53 bits to generate a double from a 64-bit random) it excludes the large majority of possible values in the range in the range [0, 1). There is an interesting debate about whether this is the right way of doing it since it is evenly distributed over the range or whether the picking should pick from the available numbers with appropriate probability.
What's more, the most common way of expanding a unit float to a broader range, have questionable behaviour due to floating point error - such as producing closed rather than open ranges and unevenly populating the possible values across a range.
Whether these details matter entirely depends on the application but they are certainly affected by the nature of floating point representation.

If i was answering this question 20+ years ago I would be able to give a much more precise answer to this question, but i shall do my best.  There are several properties to a random number generator that may matter, but whether they matter or not depends on how you are using the random numbers (and how many random numbers are needed).
Number Range
There are multiple ways to mathematically generate a sequence of numbers that have an initial appearance of being random, and usually approximating a uniform distribution over the number range. The most commonly used approaches have benefits for CPU efficiency but they also have defects that may be significant, depending on your application.
Think of these generators as formulas that can produce a long sequences of diverse numbers and that a specific seed value select a specific sequence of numbers. You then have to consider how to make a random selection of the seed value. Using time, or mouse movements or timings of key presses are strategies that have been used, but these all have their own patterns too.
Distribution Pattern
Most uses of random numbers do not want a uniform distribution of numbers and needs to transform the numbers into a distribution pattern. A common pattern is a Normal Distribution, but there are others. The ability to feed a uniform distribution into function and receive a defined non uniform distribution is crucial to a lot of statistical modelling. However, any weaknesses in the number generator tend to be exaggerated by this transformation.
Correlation
At the core of the formula pseudo number generators, there is a function that takes a number, and uses it to generate the next number in the sequence. Number generators that have flaws where the approximate value of the current number allows you to make predictions on the magnitude of the next number are problematic for simulations.
Resolution / Precision
This is actually one area where higher resolution is not always better. Imagine your number generator being fed into a distribution transform, but then, instead of working at the limits of floating point numbers, we use this number to add one to the count in a set of count buckets.  (think bars in a graph, or using a uniform distribution to generate a random dice roll between 1 and 6). Where we are able to work with resolution at a much lower level than the distortions in the generator and distribution functions, the resolution cures many of their short comings.
However, it cannot reduce or mitigate correlation faults.
Summary
The main concern raised about the precision level of floating point numbers and it creating holes in the distribution of numbers is a valid point, and can be managed with setting a resolution, but number generators have bigger weaknesses around correlation of numbers in the sequence and in the selection of the initial seed.
These weaknesses matter in the case of cryptographic key generation (brute force guessing the private key number becomes much easier if you know the generator function and can significantly shrink the range of possible seed values used)

Looking at this list of the most popular random generators, I could not find a single one which is not implemented in terms of integers.
Hence, I would expect the common random generator libraries to use integers internally, which means their internal algorithm is not affected by floating point rounding errors. However,  library functions like double Math.random() require some conversion from these integer numbers to the double range [0,1). I am not a JavaScript expert, but I could find a typical implementation of this conversion inside a random generator in the .Net framework's source code in C# here. The conversion happens in lines 94-98. Here is an excerpt from the interesting part:
 double Sample() {
      return (InternalSample()*(1.0/Int32.MaxValue));
 }
 // ..
 int InternalSample() {
 // ...

I made some minimal changes to make it more apparent what happens. InternalSample is a function only returning positive integer values, hence we get 2^31 different values at maximum.
According to this SO post, there are roughly 2^62 different double values in IEEE-754 floating points. This means the simple conversion above cannot produce all possible double values between 0.0 and 1.0, and, as you expected, there are several double values this random generator will never emit.
Note in the C# code above, there is also another private function in line 135 with an interesting comment below:
 double GetSampleForLargeRange()
      // The distribution of double value returned by Sample 
      // is not distributed well enough for a large range.
      // If we use Sample for a range [Int32.MinValue..Int32.MaxValue)
      // We will end up getting even numbers only.

That function calls InternalSample twice, to mitigate the effect mentioned in this comment for the implementation  of  int Next(int minValue, int maxValue).
Long story short: yes, the restrictions of mapping integers to float can affect the quality of the output of a random number generator function which produces double values if the implementation uses integers with a smaller range than the used floating point standard allows. The most obvious solution here would be to implement a random generator in terms of 64 bit integer arithmetic instead of 32 bit, and I am sure people have done this in the past. You have to study the documentation of your libraries and maybe their source code if you want to be 100% sure.

IBM created a linear congruential rand Jon number generator using floatingpoint arithmetic. With a fused multiply-add operation you can calculate the exact rounding error of a  multiplication and that gives you a 53 bit random number generator (very fast, they managed one number per cycle on a newer POWER processor).

Usually you generate random numbers using a pseudo random number generator using integer arithmetic only, and initialise the PRG from number from random events.
There are also for example normal distributed random numbers. They use an algorithm where you take two random numbers with linear distribution, do some floating-point calculation, and either get two normal distributed numbers or reject the results and try again. If two implementations use different floating-point arithmetic then one could reject two numbers and the other might not, so two numbers would be missing from one sequence. The rounding error is not the problem, but different rounding errors is.
The Marsaglia Polar-Method for calculating normal-distributed random numbers takes two linear distributed random numbers U and V on [-1,1], then calculates U^2 + V^2 and rejects the numbers if the sum is >= 1. When the sum is very close to 1 the outcome depends on rounding errors. If the compiler allows using a fused-multiply/add operation then different results are possible even with IEEE754 arithmetic with identical U and V. This means two calculations of a sequence of normal distributed numbers with identical seeds can give different outcomes. Unlikely but possible.
